# How to check the status of a checkbox (switch) after the submit

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

in a form i put in a checkbox (switch), how do i post after submitting to checking the status of the switch for MySQL update? thank you

Consequently the MySQL table does not change.

**From checkbox and submit**

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
<span class="mdl-switch__label">Autenticazione a due fattori</span>
</label>
....
<input onclick="conferma();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button 
mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" type="submit" 
value="Salva" name="submitBtn">
</form>
```

**Switch control and MySQL update (process.php)**

```
<?php 
session_start();
mysql_connect(localhost) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("*******") or die(mysql_error()); 
$user = $_SESSION['users'];
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) { //form submission occured
    if(!isset($_POST['switch-1'])){            
        $sql = "UPDATE `*******`.`login_users` SET `auth` = \'checked\' WHERE username = '$user'";
        header("location: https://*******.php");
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE `*******`.`login_users` SET `auth` = \'unchecked\' WHERE username = '$user'";
        header("location: https://*******.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you just put php inside js ?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, before the page is sent to the client.  It does not run on the client.

Comment: And why you put script tag and inside php?

Comment: Use ajax for this purpose

Comment: I was wrong I noticed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Modify your form

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">

    <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="switch-1" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
    <span class="mdl-switch__label">Autenticazione a due fattori</span>
    </label>
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Salva" name="submitBtn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button 
    mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" >

</form>
```

2) Create a new `process.php` page in the same working directory and add these.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['users'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "YourDBName";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) { //form submission occured

    if(isset($_POST['switch-1'])){                       
        $sql = "UPDATE login_users SET auth = 'checked' WHERE username = '$user'";
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE login_users SET auth = 'no' WHERE username = '$user'";
    }

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        echo "Updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    echo "Form Submission Error";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I did everything but MySQL does not change anything

Comment: Says successful update, but if the switch is off in MySQL it is written checked and no 'no'

Comment: Change the if(isset($_POST['switch-1'])) code. Modified above.

Comment: Now there is always 'no'

Comment: Forgot to add name="switch-1" inside input type="checkbox"

Comment: 'checked' in the <input> takes it from the data saved in MySQL